# Azure Data Explorer/kusto loosely typed json ingestion strategy

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I would like to ingest a JSONND log file with a flat structure but many possible values for keys; some keys are common, such as "time" but others vary based on the kind of log file message. What would be a useful strategy to ingest such data into Kusto/Azure Data Explorer?

I've considered the following:

- Make into columns only those keys that are always common and shove the rest as JSON into a "dynamic" data type;
- pre-parse a reasonably large sample of data, extract all possible keys and create columns for each key, defaulting to "string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach should be:

- Each property you expect to use frequently in queries (e.g. filter on, summarize on/by, etc.) should be in its own dedicated and strongly-typed (not `dynamic`) column. To achieve this, you could potentially use a [JSON ingestion mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/mappings#json-mapping) (I'm assuming the `JSONND` format will allow you to do so, but OTOTH I'm not sure how your data looks like, so you should check if that's an option), or an [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/concepts/updatepolicy).
- Properties which you expect to be less-frequently accessed can be included in a property bag ingested into a `dynamic` column (and you can access them at query time as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic#dynamic-object-accessors)).

Comment: Thanks. That’s an approach I had used in the past when playing with Spark/Avro as well.